# Message through xp_cmdshell in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, msg, xp-cmdshell

I have a question which is a 100% duplicate of [msg through sql server xp_cmdshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033644)  and I nevertheless have to ask this question again because the old question has no answer. And I cannot even add a comment to the old question because this requires reputation of 50.

My problem is: I need to send messages to my network users from within a trigger on a table in SQL Server 2014. This way I hope to find out who or what is messing up with the data in this table, probably by means of some bug planted somewhere on the network. I used to successfully use this method in the times of Windows 2000 and SQL Server 2000, and would like to use it now because it provides good results.

Unfortunately, I encounter the same problem as the author of the old question: my statement in my trigger

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'msg * Table is changed'
```

I get this error

> - does not exist or is disconnected

While from Windows command line the command `'msg * Table is changed'` works perfectly: every session on my computer immediately receives the message

I tried the suggested in the old question method of using a dedicated proxy account for xp_cmdshell but my command

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'IdeaPad\ssa', 'pas864214'; GO
```

produces the following error:

> Msg 15137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account, Line 1
> An error occurred during the execution of sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. Possible reasons: the provided account was invalid or the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential could not be created. Error code: 5(Access denied.), Error Status: 0.

Can anybody advise me how to overcome this obstacle? I issue my command under the `sa` user, who has all access to SQL Server. Why at all may he be denied access?

Or could you suggest another method of solving the problem? All other advice from the old question, including PowerShell or SQLCMD through SQL Agent, or DBMail - are ruled out because they do not provide IMMEDIATE messaging, which is essential for identifying the bug source

Comment: The `sa` account itself is only a SQL Login, not a Windows or Active Directory account, so permissions for any actions taken outside of SQL Server are based on whichever Windows or Active Directory account the SQL Server service is configured to use. (Or the `xp_cmdshell` proxy account when you have one configured.) Have you tried reading the [msg documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg) yet? There's a note, _Note: You must have Message special access permission to send a message._

Comment: Also services are running in a headless environment - there's no desktop session available to them. That might impact the ability of `msg` to function.

Comment: Why not log changes to your table into some log table? Then you can probably log the username of the person changing stuff as well.

Comment: Thank you, @siggemannen, I used the log table 20 years ago, but eventually it turned out that simple immediate message is better. This way I can query the people who sit now by their computers WHAT did they do. And this is the bug's tail, by which I can find the bug itself

Comment: I don't know if i ever agree, but i haven't used msg since prank calling people in high school. Why bother 100 people where you can bother exactly zero and get more info. You can schedule a script that checks the log table for new rows and put up a big red message on your computer and be done with this

Comment: Thank you again, @siggemannen, but your suggestion requires too much work

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer, @AlwaysLearning , I have not read msg documentation before but now I did read it, thank you. I also noted this Note concerning Message special access permission. But I did not manage to find out where this mysterious permission is located. As to the account of SQL Server - it is "NT Service\MSSQL$SERVER2014". That is how it was configured by the MSSQL installer. I do not risk to change the account because I don't know how to restore it back. So no luck anywhere, sorry. If you know how to restore back SQL Server account, tell me please

Comment: Did you try using RUNAS to run the msg command as yourself?

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way to do this. `msg` is ancient, and needs particular permissions which SQL Server shouldn't have. Use `sp_send_dbmail` if you really have to. Even then do NOT do this from a trigger. Log it to a table, then periodically check that table and send alerts. But better to just use an XEvents trace session to log all relevant commands and procedure executions.

Comment: Thank you, @Charlieface, for new ideas. I appreciate that, but you should have read what I already wrote about indispensable advantages of instant messaging. I need it, be it «absolutely wrong» or not :)) In your entire speech I don’t see any argument why I should not use instant messaging, and why should I do so much extra work to solve my problem. Your way is «absolutely right» but not efficient. Sorry, I won’t go that way

Comment: Thank you again, @siggemannen, you are definitely full of ideas. Now I did try RUNAS, my command was as follows:
DECLARE tmpstr as VarChar(255)
SET tmpstr = 'RUNAS /savecred /user:IdeaPad\ssa "msg * Table is changed from computer ' + HOST_NAME() + '"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell tmpstr

But it says «Enter password». I can and did enter password and got it saved (because of /savecred) when I ran a similar RUNAS command from Windows command line. But here from within T-SQL code there seems to be no way of doing alike. So again no luck. What would you suggest?

Comment: Reasons not do this: It won't work because the SQL service account is not a domain account. Even if it is a domain account it isn't (or at least it's a really really bad and insecure idea if it was) a domain admin so unable to send messages. Doing this using `msg` is ancient history, there are much better alerting tools available. `xp_cmdshell` is itself a security risk. Doing this from a trigger means slowing down all inserts/updates until the `msg` command has finished. Is that enough reasons?

Comment: Oh, forgot it doesn't support passwords. Ok, final try, use powershell to embed the command as well as creds. `powershell -command "& {&'Start-Process' -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('domain\user', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password123' -AsPlainText -Force))) -FilePath "notepad.exe"}"` You can also add -verb runas to force admin rights I agree this is not a good way to go in the long run though, you'd be finished already if you created the table like i wrote :)

Comment: @Charlieface, you should understand the importance of instant messaging. You seem not to care about this. As I said, there’s a bug somewhere on the network, deliberately planted by a programmer who was fired. The bug at random times writes random numbers into a table which normally is not being written to at all. So the key word here is random, which also means «rare». So there won’t be hundreds of messages per second. There would be just one in a while. And I don’t send this message to all, I send it only to my computer and my partner’s. Two computers overall.

Comment: This way we get the bug by it’s tail, because we can immediately go to computer which is source of table change and ask its owner what he had done to invoke the bug. This is efficient, while logging is not. You are probably right, the SQL Server must run under domain admin account to allow for msg.exe to work. I would try this, there is no risk because it is only for ten minutes - enough for the bug to show up. But I don’t try this because I don’t know how to restore SQL Server account back. I would be very thankful to person who tells me how to do that

Comment: @siggemannen, thank you again, but could you email me your suggestion about powershell? adlinlex@gmail.com Here in the comment there are not enough tools for text formatting, so I don’t understand what exactly you are suggesting

Comment: Don't leave us hanging, what was the bug?

Comment: @siggemannen, the bug was planted in our financial accounting software and turned out to be a procedure of about 2 kilobytes in size. It was invoked every time when somebody printed out an invoice. It did not always change the table, because of a sophisticated random algorithm. We cut the bug out, no bugs now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks everybody for your support. Finally I found the best way, based on the idea of @AlwaysLearning: temporarily change the account under which SQL Server is running. Change to the account of domain admin, or local admin in a domain-less environment. This way the msg.exe command is executing without error, I tested it.

My trigger code to catch the bug will be as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [monitor_changes] ON [dbo].[ParusNetUser] 
FOR UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @tmpstr as VarChar(255)

SET @tmpstr = 'msg * /SERVER:IdeaPad Table is changed from computer ' + HOST_NAME()
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @tmpstr, no_output
```

This way I will catch the bug in ten minutes at most. After that, I will reset the account under which SQL Server is running, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/523517/how-to-reset-the-logon-for-the-sql-server-services
That’s it, done.